# Moving article (Deleting the original) to another blog - SEO MISTAKE?

Tags: seo, google, redirects, articles, penalty

I'm trying to move an article to another blog, I already deleted the one from my blog and gave it to the other blogger, however, it is still indexed in Google, but if someone click it, he'll see a 404 error.

Now the other blogger is worried about his web site being penalyzed if he publish the article.

Thx in advance

Ps: There is no way of making a 301 permanent redirect, because the original page no longer exists.

Comment: You don't need the original page to exist to do a 301 Permanent Redirect and it would be the best way of handling this for both you and the other blogger.

Comment: You can also create 301 redirections with .htaccess if the server supports it.

Answer (score 2):

If the other blogger publishes the article, it can be not well received by Google because of [duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359). However his website wont' be penalized.

If you want avoid SEO problems, you can ask to Google to remove your webpage (article) from its index. You can do it in [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) (menu Optimization => Remove URLs). If you don't use this functionality of Webmaster Tools, Google will do it by itself.

When your webpage will be removed from Google index, the other blogger could publish article without SEO problem (if the article has non-copied content).

My answer above is relevant if you don't need other blogger page takes notoriety of your old article. Otherwise, you should do [301 redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) to his article. The aim of 301 redirect is to specify to Google that a webpage doesn't exist anymore and is replaced by a webpage located to specified URL (in 301 redirect). Indeed, to perform 301 redirect, you can use .htaccess if you use Apache Server for your website.